# Objective C how can authenticate with OAuth and do requests to get some news

Tags: objective-c, oauth, google-reader

Can someone show me how can authenticate with OAuth and do requests to get some news from google Reader?

I try with AsihttpRequest whit no results! Can someone show me is there is a better way to do that and use Oauth to get the subscrition list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the "[ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com)" framework. It can do a lot of things, including OAuth.